# How to display combined result with if statement from multiple rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table (screenshot) in database which records approval status as T1_APPROVAL for defects opened on specific date with APP_NAME.

I want to display only 1 row per APP_NAME for specific date. 
Eg. if all T1_APPROVAL='Y' where APP_NAME='APP-B' it should display Approved, else Pending.

This is what I roughly prepared so far, but doesn't give the intended result.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
     CASE WHEN t1_approval <> 'Y' THEN 'Pending' ELSE 'Approved' END
         AS status
 FROM DAV_CR_DEFECT_DPLOYMENT_STATUS
WHERE TRUNC (deploy_date) = TO_DATE ('24-JAN-2018', 'dd-mon-yyyy')
GROUP BY (t1_approval);
```

If you look at the screenshot, APP-A has one entry as N, and 1 entry as Y -- which should display as PENDING; and for APP-B all T1_APPROVAL is Y -- which should appear as APPROVED.

This is how my end result, should display like:

```
   APP_NAME |  T1_APPROVAL
   ======================
    APP-A   |  PENDING
    APP-B   |  APPROVED
```

Comment: A better date literal would be `date '2018-01-24'`. It's shorter and it will work in any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT APP_NAME,
       CASE
           WHEN AVG(ASCII(T1_APPROVAL)) = ASCII('Y')
           THEN 'APPROVED'
           ELSE 'PENDING'
       END AS T1_APPROVAL
FROM DAV_CR_DEFECT_DPLOYMENT_STATUS
WHERE TRUNC(deploy_date) = TO_DATE('24-JAN-2018', 'dd-mon-yyyy')
GROUP BY APP_NAME
```

Try that... it's been a long day, and I'm probably forgetting something stupid.

*Edit: forgot to put the date selection clause in.

Comment: This is best query based on performance. Thanks SQL Cliff. I had more data to display but your concept was awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

You want a `group by` and some conditional logic:

```
SELECT TRUNC(deploy_date), app_name, 
       (CASE WHEN MIN(TL_APPROVAL) = 'Y' THEN 'Approved' ELSE 'Pending' END) as status
FROM DAV_CR_DEFECT_DPLOYMENT_STATUS
GROUP BY TRUNC(deploy_date), app_name;
```

Comment: Returns: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Try deleting lines 3 and 4.

Comment: It's missing a comma before the second `case`. (This is why commas go on the left.)

Comment: @GurmeharSingh . . . There was some junk left over in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Take counts of `T1_APPROVAL` = `N` for every `APP_NAME` in an inner query and if it is 0 => `PENDING` else `APPROVED`.

```
SELECT A.DEPLOY_DATE, A.APP_NAME,
CASE WHEN A.PENDING_ENTRIES = 0 THEN 'APPROVED' ELSE 'PENDING' END AS T1_APPROVAL
FROM
    (SELECT TRUNC(DEPLOY_DATE) AS DEPLOY_DATE, APP_NAME,
    SUM(CASE WHEN T1_APPROVAL = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PENDING_ENTRIES
    FROM DAV_CR_DEFECT_DPLOYMENT_STATUS
    GROUP BY TRUNC(DEPLOY_DATE), APP_NAME) A;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MIN too,

```
SELECT APP_NAME,
       DECODE(MIN(T1_APPROVAL), 'Y', 'APPROVED', 'PENDING')
  FROM DAV_CR_DEFECT_DPLOYMENT_STATUS
 WHERE TRUNC(deploy_date) = TO_DATE('24-JAN-2018', 'dd-mon-yyyy')
 GROUP BY APP_NAME
```